# vim-airline: how to create a custom tabline formatter so that it contains the current directory?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In vim-airline, how to create a custom tabline formatter so that it contains the current directory? something like: `dir/filename` or `filename (dir)`. I did google this, but don't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

In `~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/formatters`, create the custom formatter, for instance, you can name it as `custom_dir_filename.vim` which has the following file content:

```
function! airline#extensions#tabline#formatters#custom_dir_filename#format(bufnr, buffers)
  let name = bufname(a:bufnr)
  return  fnamemodify(name, ':p:h:t') . '/' . fnamemodify(name, ':t')
endfunction
```

In your `.vimrc`, add the following:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'custom_dir_filename'
```

Answer (score 1):

there is already a similar one provided by airline (i found it by digging at the source code) its called short_path.

So just do
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#formatter = 'short_path'